# (Discord Py) How to make a command that checks a user's account date

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to have a command that when I say %alt <@user>, it would tell me the age of the account and if it is less than a week old, it says "Alt Found". Any way to do this?

Comment: It's not a good idea to determine whether an account is an alt or not by looking at its creation date though :D

Comment: Please [read the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.created_at)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you could do something like this

```
@bot.command()
async def CreatedAccountAt(self,ctx):
   await ctx.send(ctx.author.created_at)
```

You can also add some of your own logic in to the method to work out if to send the 'Alt Found' message at the end

Comment: This command gets the creation date of the user who used this command. The OP wants to get the creation date of the mentioned user within the command and reply with "Alt found" if the creation date was not older than 1 month.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```py
import datetime, discord

@client.event
def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    if message.content.lower().startswith("%alt"):
        target = await client.fetch_user(int(message.content.lower().replace("%alt ").replace("<","").replace(">","").replace("@","").replace("!","")[:18]))
        if float((datetime.datetime.now() - target.created_at).total_seconds()) < 2.628e+6:
            await message.reply("Alt Found!", mention_author=False)
        else:
            await message.reply("Not an alt", mention_author=False)
```

Note that 2.628e+6 represents amount of seconds in a month in a scientific notation.